# How do I cite a Stack Exchange answer in MLA?

Tags: citation, mla

I'd like to cite an answer to a Stack Exchange question in an MLA-format paper. What's the correct way to do this? Should I cite the specific answer I'm using, or the question page as a whole, and if the latter who counts as the author? Everyone whose contributed?

Word has done it as such:

```
GordonM. Why is Global State so Evil? 10 May 2012. Web Page. 21 April 2014.
    <http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil>.
```

Comment: It appears that they have a [web publications](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/08/); including "A Page on a Web Site".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eh, this is tricky. MLA doesn't have an official style for citing forums, likely because they wouldn't qualify it as valid source material for academic purposes. Oddly, though, they do have a citation recommendation for Tweets (but I imagine that's because Twitter is quickly becoming a news source).

I would try the following:

> Full name (username). Post title, answer/comment hashtag. Date and time of comment/answer. Forum post. URL.

Citing my own answer would be:

Justin (jboneca). "How do I cite a Stack Exchange answer in MLA?" #165204 . 21 April 2014. Forum post. [How do I cite a Stack Exchange answer in MLA?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165196/how-do-i-cite-a-stack-exchange-answer-in-mla/165204#165204)

Comment: Do you mean: 'Justin (jboneca). "How do I cite a Stack Exchange answer in MLA?" #165204 . Apr 21 '14 at 17:03. Forum post. [How do I cite a Stack Exchange answer in MLA?](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/165204/91759)' ? What if no full name is available?

Comment: @BCLC yep, exactly. If there were no full name provided I would simply use the username in its place.

Comment: So:' jboneca. "how...' ?