# What can I call a longer passage in an academic work (text equivalent to "Figure")?

Tags: terminology, writing-style, academia, style-manuals

I want to number blocks of texts in my work (parts of a movie script or something the creators said) so that I can refer to them throughout the essay. Is there an equivalent to 'Figure' to label these passages?

Comment: Paragraph (¶)? Section (§)? Or if you want to keep the movie reference, scene and act.

Comment: @MrLister Thanks, however I mostly want to include parts of interviews and posts & comments on social media. I bet there's an established term, I just can't find it.

Comment: Twitter feed chapter 1, paragraph 3.2?

Comment: @Conrado Reddit :) It's funny how I wouldn't have to deal with this if it weren't for the coronavirus and I could carry out classical ethnography.

Comment: Right--it is a bit un-classical and perhaps deserves an "-ography" all its own. Social media's intended flattening of all sorts of structures makes it difficult to reference, and it's transitory nature doesn't help; in all seriousness, copying the relevant "chunks" of media and numbering them as "inserts", as LPH suggests (+1), is a very good option.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165196/how-do-i-cite-a-stack-exchange-answer-in-mla

Comment: You need to determine a suitable word that could refer to parts of both interviews and social media posts, and then just use it. There is no standard. Personally, off the top of my head, I would consider [**snippet**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snippet): "a small part, piece, or thing *especially* : a brief quotable passage." I am not turning this into an answer, because I feel this question can have no answer that isn't just personal opinion. You also haven't made it clear exactly what the size range of these pieces will be, or how they will be presented.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do you call those divisions of a book bigger than a paragraph but smaller than a chapter?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26385/what-do-you-call-those-divisions-of-a-book-bigger-than-a-paragraph-but-smaller-t)

Comment: Try ***inset***. Indent that content, style the type differently, even put a border around it. Then caption: *Inset 1*, *Inset 2*, etc.  When you refer to it: *As noted in inset 3, . . .* Or skip the word in the caption and just use the number. When you refer to it: *As noted in [3], . . .*

Comment: I'm thinking you simply mean "quotation" now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If they are all pieces of another published work,

See **excerpt** 6.1 on page 43.

> An excerpt in writing is a quoted passage taken from a longer work,
>   such as a book, or poem, or an article. Whatever the subject of your
>   writing or the type of writing you intend to compose, excerpts can be
>   used to 'show' readers what it is you want them to understand and
>   remember about the subject.

https://study.com/academy/lesson/excerpt-definition-examples-quiz.html

(full article requires subscription)

Answer (score 2):

The word "insert" will do.

> (SOED) **2.** Something set in or inserted. *esp.* an extra page or pages inserted in a book etc.; a small map,  photograph, etc. inserted within the border of a larger one;

---

*Addition so as to dispel the skepticism introduced by **[user Edwin Ashworth's](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/533638/what-can-i-call-a-longer-passage-in-an-academic-work-text-equivalent-to-figure#comment1304320_533644)** comment.*

[ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=pnClL_tua_wC&pg=PA278&dq=%22see+insert%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAv-qciqfpAhUFSxoKHQz-BhQQ6AEIkgEwCg#v=onepage&q=insert&f=false)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, thanks to you, I have found some materials on this topic and it seems like no kind of labeling is established in qualitative research https://www.york.ac.uk/inst/spru/pubs/pdf/verbquotresearch.pdf

Comment: No it won't. An 'insert' is something that is inserted, not say paragraphs 22 - 37 in Chapter 6 that are already there.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Not so from the strict point of view of the definition: **a small map, photograph, etc. inserted within the border of a larger one**; the "etc" includes quite logically the word "page"; a so called minipage in LATEX does correspond to an insert according to the definition of the OED.

Comment: There's an overlap. The sections OP wishes to point out _might_ be an insert.* But the paragraphs might also have been highlighted. But that doesn't make 'highlighted sections' a sensible answer here either. [* Then again, they might also be in Swahili. In bold print. In illuminated letters. In invisible ink.}

Answer (score 2):

How about **sidebar**? From M-W:

> **[sidebar](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sidebar)**: a short news story or graphic accompanying and presenting sidelights of a major story

You could number or otherwise label the **sidebars** for easy reference.